# How does one take the transpose of an R data.table? Why doesn't t() work?

Tags: r, data.table, transpose

I have the following R data.table

```
library(data.table)
mtcars = as.data.table(mtcars)
dt = colSums(mtcars)

> dt
     mpg      cyl     disp       hp     drat       wt     qsec       vs 
 642.900  198.000 7383.100 4694.000  115.090  102.952  571.160   14.000 
      am     gear     carb 
  13.000  118.000   90.000
```

I would like to reshape the data.table `dt` as follows:

```
> transpose
column1   column2
mpg       642.900
cyl       198.000
disp      7373.100
hp        4694.000
drat      115.090
wt        102.952
qsec      571.160
vs        14.000
am        13.000
gear      118.000
carb      90.000
```

The function `t()` doesn't appear to work as expected.

```
transpose = t(dt)
```

I suspect there's a quick way to do this with `melt()` and `dcast()`, but I'm not sure how one defines each column, i.e. `column1` and `column2`

Comment: `dt` is not a data table.  Try `data.table(dt)`

Comment: Ah, I see. Simply casting `dt = as.data.table(colSums(mtcars))` appears to delete the column names though

Comment: Like Rich said. If you want to do it using a data.table syntax, you could do `melt(mtcars)[, sum(value), by = variable]`, for instance.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, post as answer?

Comment: Try `stack(dt)` if you really want to use `colSums`. It's not at all idiomatic for data.table, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
mtcars <- data.table(mtcars) # make data.table
class(mtcars) # check that it is a data.table
mtcars %>% # take the data.table
  summarise_all(funs(sum)) %>% # get the sum of each column
  gather(variable, sum) # gather all columns
```

`gather`, `spread`, and `summarise` is how I do all of my transposing. "Variable" and "sum" become the new column names:

```
   variable      sum
1       mpg  642.900
2       cyl  198.000
3      disp 7383.100
4        hp 4694.000
5      drat  115.090
6        wt  102.952
7      qsec  571.160
8        vs   14.000
9        am   13.000
10     gear  118.000
11     carb   90.000
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this to work:

```
df = as.data.table(t(as.matrix(dt)))
```

And it even preserves the names